# How to test if a jobject Class<?> reference is of a specific class (JNI)

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In JNI, how can I test if a `jobject` which is a `Class<?>` reference matches a class given by a `jclass`?

Example:

I have the following `Class<?>` reference that was passed into JNI as a native method argument:

```
jobject classRef
```

I can get the `jclass` class descriptor from the class ref as follows:

```
jclass classRefDescriptor = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, classRef);
```

I can then obtain a `jclass` reference to `int.class` as follows:

```
jclass Integer_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jclass int_class = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, Integer_class,
        (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, Integer_class, "TYPE", "Ljava/lang/Class;"));
```

Now I want to test if `classRef` is the same class reference as `int_class`.

I tried doing the following, based on how Java lets you test `if (myObject.getClass() == int.class) { ... }`:

```
if (classRefDescriptor == int_class) { ... }
```

However this doesn't work, the two `jclass` values differ by a few bits.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `classRef` is actually a `Class<T>` object, then `GetObjectClass()` will return a `jclass` instance that matches `Class<Class>`.

Why not simply use `equals`?

```
jclass clsClass = env->GetObjectClass(classRef); /* Class<Class> */
jmethodID midClassEquals = env->GetMethodID(clsClass, "equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
jboolean areEqual = env->CallBooleanMethod(classRef, midClassEquals, int_class);
```

Comment: Wait though, when you call `env->CallBooleanMethod(classRef, midClassEquals, int_class)`, you're comparing a `jobject` (`classRef`) with a `jclass` (`int_class`). Is that valid? If you pass a `jclass` to a Java method, is it treated as a `Class` instance?

Comment: The [jni specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp15954) explicitly states that jclass objects refer to Class instances. Just like jstring refers to String instances.